# XSLT transformation to get Attribute Values

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, transformation

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DatDtl xmlns="http://ups.com/ttg/cache/country">
<CnyDtl>
<Cny TslLguCd="001" CnyCd="00" Cny2Cd="DNA" Cny3Cd="000" CnyNa="Data Not Available" CnyOflNa="Data Not Available" RecEffSttDt="2010-12-31" RecEffEndDt="2099-12-31" RecUdtTs="2012-07-27 15:35:08.352773"/>
<Cny TslLguCd="001" CnyCd="96" Cny2Cd="OTH" Cny3Cd="996" CnyNa="Other" CnyOflNa="Other" RecEffSttDt="2010-12-31" RecEffEndDt="2099-12-31" RecUdtTs="2012-07-27 15:35:14.291605"/>
</CnyDtl>
</DatDtl>
```

I Would like to convert it into a CSV file with just attribute values for CnyCd and CnyNa. I have following XSLT written to extract these two values:

```
<

?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select="CnyDtl/Cny">
         <xsl:value-of select="@CnyNa"/>
<xsl:value-of select="@CnyCd"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I always get errors. What would be the correct XSLT transformation for this ?

Comment: Hello, you have to match "DatDtl" first before you can for-each "CnyDtl/Cny". Best regarsd, Peter

Comment: Don't tell us you are getting errors without telling us what errors you are getting. They may make no sense to you, but they probably make sense to the people answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your stylesheet you forgot the mention the root element `<DatDtl>`. Also don't forget to declare the namespace into your stylesheet.

If you use the following XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mypref="http://ups.com/ttg/cache/country">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="FS"> <!-- Field seperator -->
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="LT"> <!-- Line terminator -->
        <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/mypref:DatDtl">
        <xsl:for-each select="mypref:CnyDtl/mypref:Cny">
            <xsl:value-of select="@CnyNa"/>
            <xsl:value-of select=" $FS" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@CnyCd"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$LT" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will give the following output:

```
Data Not Available;00
Other;96
```